# http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd not found

Tags: spring, xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd seems to be removed from the path by VMware. I can not find any information about where any version of spring-security-oauth2.xsd can be found now.

Comment: It never has been there, the XSDs are inside the jar files and loaded from there.

Answer (score 0):

The XSD has been returned. Now the link is available again.